# Can the simulator (near_sdk_sim) be used to test cross contract calls between two different contracts?

Tags: nearprotocol

I've got the integration tests using the simulator working on my main contract, and I have a second contract which does cross contracts call to it.

Can I create simulation test which loads both contracts and runs cross contract calls?

I started to try this and it would seem that I might be able deploy two contracts such as:

```
use near_sdk_sim::{call, init_simulator, deploy, UserAccount, ContractAccount};
use contract1::Contract1Contract;
use contract2::Contract2Contract;   // <-- would need to do something different since contract2 is in a separate package
    
pub fn init()  -> (UserAccount, 
                   ContractAccount<Contract1Contract>, 
                   ContractAccount<Contract1Contract>) {

    let root = init_simulator(None);

    let contract1 : ContractAccount<Contract1Contract> = deploy!(
        contract: Contract1Contract,
        contract_id: "contract1".to_string(),
        bytes: &CONTRACT1_WASM_BYTES,
        signer_account:  root,
     );


     let contract2 : ContractAccount<Contract2Contract> = deploy!(
        contract: Contract1Contract,
        contract_id: "contract2".to_string(),
        bytes: &CONTRACT2_WASM_BYTES,
        signer_account:  root,
     );

     (root, contract1, contract2)

}
```

I realized  since the two contracts are in different packages I wasn't sure how to import the structure for contract2 one into the integration tests for contract1.

Is there a way to do this and/or and example to look at?

Does the simulator even support this? (i.e. deploying two contracts in the same test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find more here about cross contract calls: https://github.com/near-examples/cross-contract-calls

Please be aware that some of the dependencies in this repo may be a little dated at this point, but the concepts remain in tact for sure.

Comment: Thanks the example that makes sense to me -- its essentially defining a prototype for the structures that matches what is in the WASM file.     I'll give it a try